# what does this symbol mean in terms of optimization problems?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have a study

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vcgc1iDE7O8UlPHNMW3Ld18QzEP8N5Zg/view?usp=sharing

I want to understand the meaning of this symbol

[symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i06IJ.png)

Comment: $\in$ means 'belongs to', and $\setminus$ means the difference of the two sets, this is, the elements that are in the set at its left but are not in the set at its right. The whole thing means that the sum runs through all elements $j$ that belong to $N$ but are not $i$.

Comment: And note that this notation is not particular to optimization problems. This is standard set theoretic notation in any field of mathematics. (You might sometimes see $N-\{j\}$ instead of $N\setminus \{j\}$ though.)

Comment: @ user647486  why does he put in the rest of the constraint that i  ∈ N ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A\setminus B$ is the set of all the objects that are in the set $A$ but not in the set $B$. Therefore, if the notations in the two links are consistent, $j\in N\setminus \{i\}$ should mean whatever $$j\text{ is a }``\text{damaged component and depot'' different from }i$$ means.

Comment: why does he put in the rest of the constraint that i ∈ N ?

Comment: @omarkhater I don't know. You're the one reading the article; I am not.

Comment: Thank you for your help